# How to convert received data Array in Buffer type after python flush the stdout to nodejs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I have a nodejs backend called a python script and then used stdout.flush to send the json to nodejs backend.

at the end of the python script:

```
sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(json_dict))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

on nodejs backend:

```
app.get('/records', (req, res) => {
    const { spawn } = require('child_process');
    const pyProg = spawn('python', ['script.py']);
    pyProg.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
        return res.json({ success: true, data });
    });
})
```

Then I used fetch to get the data in frontend:

```
fetch('/records')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.success && response.data) {
                console.log(response.data);
```

when I print the response.data in console i got is like this:
`{type: 'Buffer', data: Array(389)}`

How can I get the json_dict in json format or string format in the frontend so i can display the content?  All i got are 389 numbers like this:

```
data: 
Array(389)
[0 … 99]
[100 … 199]
[200 … 299]
[300 … 388]
length: 389
```

I tried many ways to convert the Array(389) but not working. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On the backend, you can send the data as a string to the frontend**

```
app.get('/records', (req, res) => {
    const { spawn } = require('child_process');
    const pyProg = spawn('python', ['script.py']);
    pyProg.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        // Parse the string as JSON
        const jsonData = JSON.parse(data.toString());
        // Send the JSON object to the frontend
        return res.json({ success: true, data: jsonData });
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you, it works, after i posted the question i realise the array of numbers i got are actually the ascii code of the json string. your method is cleaner.

Comment: hey levy, i saw you edited the answer, so i also tried this version, but i got a type error in frontend, not sure why but i have to pass string to frontend instead of json.